# How do I stream a Canvas Object from a child process back to Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, phantomjs, child-process

I am using the headless Browser Engine PhantomJS to create a Canvas Object.
I've spawned a child process from Node.js to Phantom.
How do I get the Canvas in my parent Process (read Node.js)?
I've tried stdout.write(sourcecanvas) and then assigning sourcecanvas to a variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please show your code. You probably have a problem with `page.evaluate()` being sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

Headless or not, 
Canvas is a **frontend** Item. This is in the browser part of the javascript. You need to post data from that canvas in your app to send it to nodejs (Which is the **server** part).

In order to do the post from javascript, you can do something like this:

```
    context.drawImage(output, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ....  // more canvas drawings.
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    dataURL = dataURL.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'yoururl/path',
        data: dataURL , 
    });
```